# Regex needed to remove and replace specified html tags in two criteria's using C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex

1) REPLACE only few html tags with respective html tag.

Example: Replace h1 tag with h4 tags and replace div tag with p tag.

Input:

```
<div><h1>First</h1><h1 align='center'>Second</h1></div><span>third</span>
```

Expected Output:

```
<p><h4>First</h4><h4 align='center'>Second</h4></p><span>third</span>
```

2) REMOVE only few html tags

Example: Remove div and h1 tags.

Input:

```
<div><h4>First</h4><h1 align='center'>Second</h1></div>
```

Expected output:

```
<h4>First</h4>Second
```

fyi: I tried using

```html
Regex.Replace(html, @"</?h1>", "")
```

but it doesn't remove if the tag has attributes.

Comment: Parsing html with regex.... what could go wrong.

Comment: While accepted answer solves you immediate problem your question as it asked is broader and fits into duplicate of standard "parse HTML with regex". Please make sure to read answers after first several once that go in a lot of details why it is hard, what framework specific features of regular expressions you can use and more importatnly what are recommended alternatives (i.e. for C# HtmlAgilityPack is common and easier to use solution if your HTML is not coming from one well fixed source).

Comment: Link to the question: [parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use capture groups in your regex and use them in the substitution according to the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z

```
//to remove all h1 tags:
Regex.Replace(html, @"</?h1[^>]*>", "")

//to replace all div tags with p, keeping the same attributes:
Regex.Replace(html, @"(</?)div([^>]*>)", "$1p$2")

//to change the attributes of the div tags you will need two regexes:
//one for the opening tags
Regex.Replace(html, @"<div[^>]*>", "<p class='content'>")
//one for the closing tag
Regex.Replace(html, @"</div>", "</p>")
```

The last example was added to answer a comment, and the reason why it needs to be two is because the new part of the string (which will be added) is different.

Comment: thank you DANIEL  1) Can you add regex to replace tag excluding the attributes and also with new tag with attributes. Example replace <div align='center'></div> with <p class='content'></p>.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the regex `</?(h1|div)[^>]*>`? (Or, in case you want only `h1` tags removed, `</?h1[^>]*>`?)